# ls command - switch the output rows to columns

Tags: command-line, ls

Is there any way possible to change output of `ls`?
Normally `ls` displays something like this:

```
something something1 something2 something3 

something4 something5 something6 something7
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
1. something        5. something4
2. something1       6. something5
3. something2       7. something6
4. something3       8. something7
```

Is there any simple command to handle this case, without using loops and many lines of code?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and add an actual example of `ls -l`'s output and the desired one? What do you mean by all those _somethings_? Are they the `ls -l`'s columns (like timestamp, size, permissions, etc.)?

Comment: That's not how `ls -l` outputs things.

Comment: Read `man ls` - there are many ways to distort the output.

Answer (score 6):

`ls -C` sorts the files in the current directory in columns. In addition you can limit the width of the output with `-w`. `ls -x` sorts the output in lines. (`man ls` gives you a lot of other options.)

So in your example:

```
$ ls
something   something2  something4  something6
something1  something3  something5  something7
$ ls -x                                         # different ordering
something   something1  something2  something3
something4  something5  something6  something7
$ ls -C                                         # same as ls
something   something2  something4  something6
something1  something3  something5  something7
$ ls -C -w 30                                   # same as ls -w 30
something   something4
something1  something5
something2  something6
something3  something7
```

BTW: The output given in your question is certainly not the output of `ls -l`, but of `ls`.

Answer (score 6):

To obtain 2 numbered columns, try:

```
ls | pr -2Tn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using this a lot and want to sequentially number the items listed, I'd consider making a script you can call when needed for this.

Here's a script that will do what you need. Save this to a shell script file... I've named mine 'numberlist.sh'. When you want to enumerate a list of files, change your working directory (cd) to that folder and then call this script with 'sh /filepath/numberlist.sh'

```
#!/bin/bash

#set a count variable for loop
i=1
#set a formatting for printf
fmt="%-15s\n"
#get working directory
curdir=${PWD}/

#get list of files only, exclude directories
onlyfiles=$(ls -p $curdir | grep -v /)
#create temp file to hold list
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/filelist.XXXXXX)
#iterate through list of files
#number them and add to tempfile
for item in $onlyfiles; do
    printf "$fmt" "$i"."$item" >> "$tmpfile"
    i=$(($i+1))
done

#print the list in columnar order
cat $tmpfile | column
#remove the temp file
rm $tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0):

JJoao's answer is something I wasn't aware of... seems you could do that as well. If you wanted to prevent listing directories however, you'd do:

```
ls -l | grep -v / | pr -2n
```

However, the formatting is different so it breaks long lists into "pages".

EDIT: missed the -T option. That will omit the "pages". So this is a good option

Comment: you can also use -l1 to specify only 1 line instead of pages. `ls -l | grep -v / | pr -2n -l1`